# Name of 'Container' as an entity is not allowed in Web API OData

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-odata

My list of entities includes one called 'Container'.  (My company deals with containers a lot and it is a fairly "Set In Stone" term.)

So when I modeled my data for them, I naturally called them Containers.

That means I have a class called `Container`.

I just got done wiring up all my controllers for Web API OData and when I try to compile a client using it, I get an error.  (I am using the WCF Data Service Client nuget package.)

The error is because there is my entity's `Container` partial class and another partial class that holds all the root level collections, also called `Container`.  (NOTE: I don't get this error for my service that is running the same entities via WCF Data Services version of OData.)

So, my question is: **Is there any way to have an entity called `Container` and expose it over Web Api OData?** (and not get the client compile time errors).

*NOTE: If you try to repro this, the error occurs if the entity called 'Container' has an association to a something that is also a root item (so it is included in the DataServiceContext class called 'Cntainer'.  For example if the Containers has an List of possible ContainerTypes and there is a root list of ContainerTypes then the parital classes try to merge and there is a conflict.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the ODataModelBuilder (that you use to define all your entity sets) has a ContainerName property.

Setting that gives you a different name than the default of "Container"

```
ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.ContainerName = "YourCustomContainerNameHere";
```

Comment: Please mark your answer as the answer. Practically the same issue was solved by your response.